# Calculate parametric bounds of a circle in a 2D quadrilateral

Tags: circles, parametric, quadrilateral

Given a 2D quadrilateral defined by the points $(p0, p1, p2, p3)$ and a circle centered at $c$ with a radius of $r$, I want to find a quad in the parametric space of the outer quad that tightly bounds the circle.

The outer quad is convex but otherwise arbitrary.

The inner quad is limited in that the top points share a $v$ component, the bottom points share a different $v$ component, and the same for the $u$ components of the left and right sides.

In the diagram below I've labeled the parametric values I'm looking for as $u0$, $u1$, $v0$, and $v1$.

[image: Diagram of the circle and the outer and inner quads]